# google coding jam round b 2019 building plaindrome keeps throwing runtime error

Tags: python, python-3.x

## occ() returns 1 if can be transformed into plaindrome else 0

```
        def occ(A):
            odd = 0
            for a in A:
                if a % 2 != 0:  # is odd
                    odd += 1
                    if odd > 1:
                        return 0
            return 1
```

## main function

```
        p = int(input())
        for f in range(1,p+1):
            n,q = map(long,input().split())
            sample= input()
            c=0
            for i in range(q):
                s,e = map(int,input().split())
                c=c+occ(sample[s-1:e+1])
            print("Case #"+str(f)+": "+str(c))
```

Comment: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050eda/0000000000119866

Comment: Can you share exact full error message, also have you tried debugging it? Can you point out around which lines the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

1. `long(n)` is not a function, `int(n)` is. Python tells you this in the following error message:

```
s,e = map(long,input().split())
NameError: name 'long' is not defined    <-- HERE it says "long" does not exist
```

In Python, `int`s have no limit, so a `long` data type is not needed. This line should be changed to:

```
s,e = map(int,input().split())
```

2. The sample subsequence is incorrect. Currently, it is `sample[s-1:e+1]`, but it should be `sample[s-1:e]`. Try it out on a piece of paper to check it yourself.
3. The `occ(A)` method you posted  is incomplete. You don't want to check if each letter is odd or even, that doesn't make sense. You want to check if there is only one letter that occurs an odd number of times in the substring. Below is a fix.

```
def occ(substring):
    letter_count = [0 for _ in range(26)]
    for c in substring:
        letter_count[ord(c) - ord("A")] += 1
    # The code below is the original occ
    odd = 0
    for a in letter_count:
        if a % 2 != 0:
            odd += 1
        if odd > 1:
            return 0
    return 1
```